# How to solve that a Base class with a pointer to Base must be pointer to Son?(in C++)

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance

If i want to have a class like this:

```
struct NodeLvl1 {
    NodeLvl1* parent;
};
```

everything okay, because NodeLvl1 points to another one, and so one. But if i want to make an advance version of it:

```
struct NodeLvl2 : NodeLvl1 {//Also have a NodeLvl1*
    int extra_value;
};
```

The problem is that parent in a `NodeLvl2` class there is a pointer to `NodeLvl1` instead of a pointer of `NodeLvl2` as i would like. What is your best way to solve this? i thinking about a `BaseNode` or using templates. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You might be looking for the [CRTP pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). What are you trying to make with this data structure though? It's hard to give good advice here without more context.

Comment: Thoes are for Binary Heaps and Search Binaryh Trees, but thats actually a good pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm understanding the question correctly, since I'm not sure what the use case is.  But here's a try...

```
struct NodeLvl1 {
    NodeLvl1(NodeLvl1 *child) : childAddr(child) {}
    NodeLvl1* childAddr;
};

struct NodeLvl2 : NodeLvl1 {
    NodeLvl2(const int value) : NodeLvl1(this), extra_value(value) {}
    int extra_value;
};
```

This will have the address of the child struct stored in the parent struct.  You can confirm this with below:

```
int main() {
    NodeLvl2 child(3);  // random extra_value
    std::cout << &child << " " << child.childAddr << std::endl; // displays addresses
    return 0;
}
```

Not sure that's what you're looking for though.